# SqlAlchemy - Retrieve long text from oracle db

Tags: python-3.x, database, sqlalchemy, scripting, cx-oracle

I'm trying to run few queries/stored procs which will return a long text (varchar2/clob), eg: Table/View/etc ddl. Will be getting the long text, do some manipulation & store in a flat file.

I'm getting below output which is a truncated version (highlighted) of the whole thing:

```
("DROP VIEW <<view>>;\n\n/* Formatted on 27/05/2022 7:08:33 PM (QP5 v5.354) */\nCREATE OR REPLACE FORCE 
VIEW <<view>> ... **(1097 characters truncated)** ... tx', '<<some value>>'),\n                                     'YYYYMMDD');
\n\n\nGRANT <<rights>>> ON <<view>> TO <<user>>;\n",)
```

I'm using below code:

```py
conn_db = create_engine('oracle://<<user>>:<<pass>>@<<db_service>>')`
with conn_db.connect() as connection:
    res = connection.execute("<<query/proc>>")
    for row in res:
        print(row) # this returns the above output
```

I've tried setting the arraysize while engine creation but didn't work.

Comment: `arraysize` is a tuning parameter that affects internal buffer sizing when fetching multiple rows.  It is not directly related to LOBs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print(row)` is truncating the string for display purposes. The actual string is unaffected:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine("oracle+cx_oracle://scott:tiger@192.168.0.199/?service_name=xepdb1")

s = " ".join(["spam" for i in range(200)])
with engine.connect() as conn:
    row = conn.exec_driver_sql("SELECT :s AS spam FROM DUAL", {"s": s}).one()
    print(row)
    # ('spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam ... (701 characters truncated) ... spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam',)
    #
    # [scroll right to see "... (701 characters truncated) ..."]
    #
    spam = row.spam
    print(len(spam))  # 999
    print(spam)
    # spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam spam
```

Comment: It was the case. Thank you for pointing it out.